# How to create a cursor with ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, ios-charts

Is there a way to create a cursor with ios-charts in a LineGraph in the x-axys?
[image]
I read all the doc. but the most similar thing that I found ware the Markers.

Comment: Do you need the only vertical line and is movable by tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight value by enable `chartDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true)` it will show highlighted value with vertical line on your lineChart.

**Swift Code :**

```
let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: label)

chartDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true)

chartDataSet.highlightColor = .blue
chartDataSet.highlightLineWidth = 1
```

By above code you can enable this vertical line.

sample screen shot :

[image]

Hope this will helps to highlight your Value in line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may disable horizontal Highlight Indicator by next line:

```
dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
```